# logging a telnet session as a background process

Tags: bash, background-process, telnet, expect

I want to achieve the following: We have a telecommunications system which protocols all incoming and outgoing calls and makes the data acessible live via telnet. What I want to do is to run a background script on a Debian VM that is permanently connected with the system and logs the data.
After a bit of research (I am very unfamiliar with shell scripting) I decided to make use of the tools script and expect.
The logging part works so far; the background part not so well. I show you the two scripts I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
script -f -q -c"./autotelnet.sh 192.168.xxx.xxx mylogin mypassword" -a output.log &
```

and this is the script for the automated telnet connection:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#autotelnet.sh
set timeout 20
set name [lindex $argv 0]
set port [lindex $argv 1]
set user [lindex $argv 2]
set password [lindex $argv 3]
spawn telnet $name $port
expect "Escape character is '^]'.-" #This is the actual login name prompt. 
send "$user\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$password\r"
interact
```

now if I just type "./telefonlog &" it doesn't start in the background despite the ampersand in the first script, but everything gets logged as it should. (Btw, I can't get the CTRL-Z into bg command to work while in the telnet session). How can I force the expect script to stay in the background?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try "expect_background". More details on "http://linux.about.com/od/commands/a/The-Linux-Unix-Command-Expect_2.htm".